# Magento Multi-flat shipping module and free shipping

Tags: magento

Good day,

I am currently working on an important magento project and i need to add option of zero prices for shipping options in the event that the price of this order will be above € 33.
I installed this module:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-flat-shipping-1.html

Picture to explain of my problem:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming - in fact you haven't actually asked a question. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

In the extenion Abstract Class `MSP_FlatShipping5_Model_Carrier_Abstract` located at `app\code\community\MSP\FlatShipping5\Model\Carrier\Abstract.php`, You need to add below code:

```
if ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() > 33 ) {
    $shippingPrice = '0.00';
}
```

In collectRates function below this line of code, around line no 90:

```
if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes()) {
    $shippingPrice = '0.00';
}
```

To create this code more manageable, you can create free shipping amount field using `system.xml` and fetch the same field.